# ASP.NET MVC quick start - a one-stop tutorial?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There are many ASP.MVC blog post bits and pieces scattered over different web sites, as well as couple of resource questions here - [ASP.NET Model-view-controller (MVC) - where do I start from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599/aspnet-model-view-controller-mvc-where-do-i-start-from) and [MVC Learning Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425/mvc-learning-resources)

I wonder if there was a one-stop tutorial posted yet on getting started with ASP.NET MVC?

Thank you!

**Edit:** I probably need to clarify - a one-stop tutorial that'd help to get started within and hour or two and learn more as I go... Reading books is a non starter for me personally - takes more time I can afford and starts with basics...

Comment: Note that most of answers on this post haven't been updated since 08 or 09 (which seems to be around the time that the very first version of ASP.NET MVC was created); readers looking for recent information should probably keep looking... If you're confused by the .NET Core version numbers, I mean that the answers on this question target ASP.NET MVC version 1.0 (which is circa 2009-ish, ASP.NET MVC is currently on version 5 or 6), not ASP.NET **Core** MVC 1.x (which is fairly recent).

Comment: Also for what it's worth it seems like the [Microsoft docs "Getting Started" page for MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) is pretty decent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you looked at [MVC Samples](http://www.codeplex.com/mvcsamples) on CodePlex? Rob Conery has some screencasts that go along with the creation of the site at http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/.

Comment: The Rob Conery screencasts are provided on the ASP.NET MVC website.

Answer (score 5):

Scott Guthrie wrote a free complete end to end tutorial of creating a full web application using MVC and it touches on most of the major pieces of MVC:

- [NerdDinner.com](http://nerddinner.com/)
- [Code Walkthrough of how to build NerdDinner.com](http://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget [Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/).  Latest news on MVC.  The "official" site is two releases behind.

Comment: Some of the information is, but they do keep it updated as the new bits come out.  There have been quite of few videos released in the past month or so.

Comment: Also, some of the links in the question he referred to has Scott Guthrie's blog in it.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.asp.net/mvc

Whoops, submitted before I was done.  The ASP.NET MVC site has tons of videos/screencast on getting started with ASP.NET MVC.  Definitely watch the Scott Hanselman ones first.

#### Edit

The Rob Conery screencasts that [@David provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668/aspnet-mvc-quick-start-a-one-stop-tutorial#52675) are provided on the [ASP.NET MVC site](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/) also, under videos.  That would constitute one spot to get those resources and also the ones the ASP.NET MVC team put out.

One note on any resource you use.  You could run into functionality that is no longer available in the framework due to it being in development.  If you use the resources provided that you already found along with the tutorials, you will find the replacements or how to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

[Quickstart](http://quickstarts.asp.net/3-5-extensions/mvc/MVCOverview.aspx) gives a good overview of all features.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, as we get closer to release, http://asp.net/mvc will be the one stop shop for ASP.NET MVC related issues.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above mentioned:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther
- [Asp.net MVC in Action](http://www.manning.com/palermo/) looks to be a good book.

Answer (score 0):

We just recently released the beta version of [TheBeerHouse MVC Edition](http://www.codeplex.com/TheBeerHouse/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx) which should give you some great examples. There is also a book written explaining everything, but you will have to wait a little longer for that to come out :D.