# Asp.NET MVC Tutorials and Books

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC quick start - a one-stop tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668/asp-net-mvc-quick-start-a-one-stop-tutorial)

I am starting a new Asp.NET MVC project and want to know from you guys how to a nice recommedable books and tutorials. Don't tell me to google.

[EDITED]

I need books with Tutorial videos, Sample Codes(Preferable Sample Real World Project), Like the Bear House in Asp.NET, easily understandable step by step elaborated once.

Comment: Don't google, use the search box on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Asp.NET+MVC+tutorial+book

Comment: Try [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-Jon-Galloway/dp/1118076583) and try [this app](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/)

Comment: This question will likely be closed soon since it's been asked before but you could definitely gain some good knowledge from pluralsight's videos:  http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/Index  Not free, but not terribly expensive either.

Comment: yes, before this is closed. Make sure you view this FREE one from pluralsight. http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's definitely [MVC Music store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) you should take a look at. Rob Conery's videos. 
[This](http://www.asp.net/mvc), [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos) and [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials).

That's for the beginning. Then you will soon be searching for custom stuff on routes, localization, view models, action filters etc.